# Set Up Rest Parameters for .execute()

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, parameters, discord.js

I simply want to be able to get all the parameters ill need for a command from a `components` object.

```
const components = {
    args,
    member,
    message,
    MessageEmbed,
    guild
}

switch (command) {

    case 'ping':
        return bot.commands.get('ping').execute(components)
    break

}
```

Whenever Executing The Command, The parameters needed return `undefined`. How can I set up an object, or even an array that can take place off all the parameters to then be passed into `execute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const components = {
  // quotations are needed for keys with spaces
  args: args,
  "member": member,
  "message": message,
  "guild": guild
};

switch (command) {
  case 'ping':
    return bot.commands.get('ping').execute(components);
    break;
}

// ping's execute function
function execute(components) {
  const args = components.args;
  const member = components["member"];
}
```